# Git Immersion Lab 49

Tags: git

Here is the link to the lab: [lab49](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_49.html).

You might need to check the previous labs for the context.

---

I don't understand what is the point of this command:

```
git branch --track shared master
```

My understanding is that, this command create a branch named `shared`, which is exactly same as the branch `master`.

But the `master` branch is a local branch of `cloned_hello`. I think what the author meant is to track the remote branch `shared/master`.

```
git branch --track shared shared/master
```

Comment: I think you're right. The command creates an unnecessary branch named `shared`.